# How can i autocomplete the place search in magento?

Tags: magento

In my website there is an option for customer to select their delivery location.Now the location is loaded from database.I want to load it from google location,and also want to show suggestions when user enter letters.

Comment: you need to customize the current functionality, so it take data from google instade of database.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?